# Can't appy css to the dynamically added lightning-combobox

Tags: css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Can't able to add the CSS to the dynamically added tags in **"lightning:combobox"**. Below is the marked code which is adding dynamically. However, I tried to target the input via parent class but it's not reflecting after adding to the CSS code. Wanted to add the border to this input and hide the **label** inside it for the **empty one**.

[image]

Comment: Are you building on the Salesforce platform? You can't apply CSS inside a standard component.

Comment: @DavidReed - Yes, I am building in the salesforce platform. There must be some solution for that because on the other page it's coming fine all the dropdown border is coming fine. But specially for this page, it's not coming. However, I have taken the same code from the other page.